# Day 9 Advent of Code

Tags: python, shortest-path, brute-force

I am attempting to get caught up on my [adventofcode.com](http://adventofcode.com/day/9)

solutions (currently on day 9) but said day is proving to be a little tricky.

I've gotten the others just fine (It has taken awhile but eventually I solved all of them).

This one however I just can't wrap my head around. I've never attempted a problem like this before and am having trouble generating every permutation of cities.

Once I do this, I can just *min()* to find the shortest path, but my solution is proving to be ineffective (the answer remains too high).

Current solution:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2.7

destinations = open('day9.txt', 'r').read().split('\n')
distances = []

for dest in destinations:
    dest = dest.split()
    distances.append(int(dest[-1]))

    for sub_dest in destinations:
        sub_dest = sub_dest.split()

        if dest == sub_dest:
            continue

        distances[-1] += int(sub_dest[-1])

print min(set(distances))
```

and day9.txt:

```
Tristram to AlphaCentauri = 34
Tristram to Snowdin = 100
Tristram to Tambi = 63
Tristram to Faerun = 108
Tristram to Norrath = 111
Tristram to Straylight = 89
Tristram to Arbre = 132
AlphaCentauri to Snowdin = 4
AlphaCentauri to Tambi = 79
AlphaCentauri to Faerun = 44
AlphaCentauri to Norrath = 147
AlphaCentauri to Straylight = 133
AlphaCentauri to Arbre = 74
Snowdin to Tambi = 105
Snowdin to Faerun = 95
Snowdin to Norrath = 48
Snowdin to Straylight = 88
Snowdin to Arbre = 7
Tambi to Faerun = 68
Tambi to Norrath = 134
Tambi to Straylight = 107
Tambi to Arbre = 40
Faerun to Norrath = 11
Faerun to Straylight = 66
Faerun to Arbre = 144
Norrath to Straylight = 115
Norrath to Arbre = 135
Straylight to Arbre = 127
```

Comment: and the problem statement is?

Comment: err sorry... meant to put it in at the end and slipped my mind.edited

Answer (score 1):

To list all permutations of your cities (or any list) you can use itertools.permutations:

```
>>> from itertools import permutations
>>> for p in permutations(["London", "Belfast", "Dublin"]):
...   print p
... 
('London', 'Belfast', 'Dublin')
('London', 'Dublin', 'Belfast')
('Belfast', 'London', 'Dublin')
('Belfast', 'Dublin', 'London')
('Dublin', 'London', 'Belfast')
('Dublin', 'Belfast', 'London')
```

if you want to implent yourself the `permutations` function just think that every permutation is obtained by choosing the first city among all possible cities, and then join all the possible permutations of remaining cities...

Possible solution:

```
data = {}  # (city_from, city_to) -> distance                                                                                                 
for line in open("day9.txt"):
    start, to, end, equals, distance = line.split()
    assert to == "to"
    assert equals == "="
    data[(start, end)] = data[(end, start)] = int(distance)

cities = list(set([key[0] for key in data]))

def permutations(lst):
    if not lst:
        yield []
    for i, first in enumerate(lst):
        for rest in permutations(lst[:i]+lst[i+1:]):
            yield [first] + rest

minimal_cost = float("inf")
best_path = None
for perm in permutations(cities):
    cost = sum([data[couple] for couple in zip(perm[:-1], perm[1:])])
    if cost < minimal_cost:
        minimal_cost = cost
        best_path = perm

print best_path
print minimal_cost
```